# Can't create a RTC_DATA_ATTR var inside a class

Tags: esp32, sleep

I'm trying to create a deepSleep class for my ESP32 project, but I get this error : `section attribute not allowed for 'clock_beforeSleep'` The only place it compiles, is outside the class.

How should I declare it ?

**EDIT1**: Add Code

```
#include "EEPROM.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "WiFi.h"

RTC_DATA_ATTR long clock_expectedWake = 0;
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootCounter = 0;
RTC_DATA_ATTR int driftRTC = 0;
RTC_DATA_ATTR long clock_beforeSleep = 0;

class esp32Sleep
{
#define EEPROM_SIZE 16
#define DEV_NAME "ESP32lite"
#define uS_TO_S_FACTOR 1000000ULL /* Conversion micro seconds to seconds */

private:
  char sleepstr[250];
  // RTC_DATA_ATTR long clock_expectedWake = 0;
.
.
.
```

Comment: a class member is only a declaration. it has a space in memory only if an object of that class is created. you could try `static` keyword. static members are common for all instances of that class

Comment: @Juraj but it is a `TRV_DATA_ATTR` which stores its value and retrieves after awakening.

Comment: I know and that is the reason why it can't be a class member. the linker puts it at address in RTC memory

Comment: @Juraj - see edit 1. can you please explain about "linker"

Comment: linker follows a linker script, which specifies what goes where in memory https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/1977370e6fc069e93ffd8818798fbfda27ae7d99/tools/sdk/ld/esp32.project.ld#L48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put an `RTC_DATA_ATTR` qualified variable inside a class because the class is stored in normal RAM. The `RTC_DATA_ATTR` qualified variable is, by definition, stored in RTC RAM.

The definition of `RTC_DATA_ATTR` includes a `section` attribute (`__attribute__((section(".rtc.data")))`) that tells the compiler where abouts in memory the variable should be stored (in this case the 8kiB of "slow" RTC memory). That is mutually exclusive with where the compiler decides to store the class.

It's like you have a diamond necklace which the has to be kept in a safe at all times, but you want to wear it around your neck *whilst at the same time storing it in the safe*. You can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think some explanation about the different allocation schemes could be
useful:

- Global variables, as well as static locals and static class members,
  are allocated at build time, by the linker, typically in the .data or
  .bss section of the program.
- Local variables are allocated at run time in the stack. Typically the
  compiler issues some instructions to adjust the stack pointer in order
  to make room for the variable. As an optimization, the most used
  locals can be stored directly in CPU registers, but this optimization
  is disabled if you use the address of the variable.
- Variables created with `new` and `malloc()` are allocated at run time
  in the heap. This allocation is handled by a support library.

Note that objects are variables and are allocated in one piece, just
like a C `struct`. Static class members are not part of the class
instances.

Now, some build chains have extensions that allow you to store
statically allocated variables elsewhere than the RAM. One example is
the `PROGMEM` storage on AVR. `RTC_DATA_ATTR` sounds like a similar
extension. You may be able to store a regular class member this way if:

1. The object is global and stored as `RTC_DATA_ATTR` as a whole.
2. It doesn't need a constructor.

Comment: Is there a workaround the make such class?